# How to port forward on my huawei modem (b525s-23a) Minecraft Server

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, modem

I want to port forward for my Minecraft server. I've literally tried everything. I literally don't know how to configure any of the stuff I've tried correctly. I would like someone to tell me how to do it and how it works.

[image]

Comment: [How To Port Forward Minecraft](https://portforward.com/softwareguides/minecraft/portforward-minecraft.htm)

Comment: [Easiest Way to Forward Ports on the Huawei B593s-22 Router](https://portforward.com/huawei/b593s-22/)